# exporting react class with AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, react-router

I have this code below being rendered to make sure that the code works. Now that I have it working, I'm trying to export it into my Index page using the following: . Can someone please provide guidance as to how I go about exporting it?

```js
class EmployeeRow extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.item.AccountID}</td>
                <td>{this.props.item.AccountName}</td>
                <td>{this.props.item.SenderName}</td>
                <td>{this.props.item.SenderEmail}</td>
                <td>{this.props.item.ITEmailReceipients}</td>
                <td>{this.props.item.Active}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
} 
 class EmployeeTable extends React.Component {
    state = {
        result: []
    }

    render() {
        var rows = [];
        this.state.result.forEach(function (item) {
            rows.push(<EmployeeRow key={item.AccountID} item={item} />);
        });
        return (
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>EmployeeID</th>
                        <th>FirstName</th>
                        <th>LastName</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Designation</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    {rows}
                </tbody>
        </table>);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', this.props.url, true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            this.setState({ result: response });
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.send();
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<EmployeeTable url="GetEmployeeData" />,
    document.getElementById('griddata')
);
```

Index.js

```js
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

import GSC from './GSC';
import Intro from './Intro';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
            <div className="App">

                <Route exact path='/' component={Intro} />
                <Route exact path='/Home/GSC' render={() => <EmployeeTable url="GetEmployeeData" />} />

            </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

As you can see, I'm using a router so when the user is on the Index Page it displays a message from there. And when the user Clicks on a URL it takes them to the /Home/GSC site. This GSC site doesn't seem to render when I export it to the Index.js file. Any ideas on why that is happening and how to work it out?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. Could you elaborate? [Do you mean how you export the `EmployeeTable` component and import it somewhere else](https://codesandbox.io/s/mo3wp8nnp8)?

Comment: Yes exactly, however if you look at the bottom of the code I have a prop and it's looking for a div item that's on a different html.

Comment: Alright. What are you struggling with? Doesn't it work in your app if you export the component and render it somewhere else?

Comment: It's not working. On my Index page I'm using this: <Route exact path='/Home/GSC' component={GSC} />. But it doesn't seem to work. am I missing a step or not understanding how to pass a class with a prop: <EmployeeTable url="GetEmployeeData" />.?

Comment: Ah, I see. You should include that that's what you are trying to do in your question. You can use the render prop instead: `<Route exact path='/Home/GSC' render={() => <EmployeeTable url="GetEmployeeData" />} />`

Comment: Actually that worked!! I had to make one small change in GSC. The div id also needed to be 'app'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Route exact path='/Home/GSC' render={() => <EmployeeTable url="GetEmployeeData" />} />
```

As stated by Tholle.